# Is everything reinstalled from scratch in cabal sandboxes?

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

Let's assume the following procedure:

`cd /home/user/experiment`

`git clone https://github.com/ryantrinkle/reflex.git`

`cabal sandbox init`

`cabal install --dependencies-only`

**Question:**

At this point what packages will the sandbox in `/home/user/experiment` contain ? Will it contain the **whole dependency hierarchy tree** of Reflex ?

In other words, if Reflex is the root package then will the whole dependency tree of Reflex be compiled **from scratch**  **independently** of what is installed already in the global package repository of cabal ?

I suspect yes, but I am not sure.

When I execute the above command sequence then the following packages are installed :

```
[vagrant@localhost reflex]$ cabal install --only-dependencies
Resolving dependencies...
Notice: installing into a sandbox located at /home/vagrant/reflex
Downloading dependent-sum-0.2.1.0...
Configuring base-orphans-0.3.3...
Downloading primitive-0.5.4.0...
Configuring mtl-2.2.1...
Building base-orphans-0.3.3...
Building mtl-2.2.1...
Installed base-orphans-0.3.3
Configuring nats-1...
Building nats-1...
Installed nats-1
Configuring stm-2.4.4...
Configuring tagged-0.8.0.1...
Installed mtl-2.2.1
Building stm-2.4.4...
Building tagged-0.8.0.1...
Configuring text-1.2.1.1...
Installed stm-2.4.4
Downloading ref-tf-0.4...
Configuring transformers-compat-0.4.0.4...
Installed tagged-0.8.0.1
Building text-1.2.1.1...
Building transformers-compat-0.4.0.4...
Configuring dependent-sum-0.2.1.0...
Installed transformers-compat-0.4.0.4
Building dependent-sum-0.2.1.0...
Configuring primitive-0.5.4.0...
Installed dependent-sum-0.2.1.0
Downloading dependent-map-0.1.1.3...
Building primitive-0.5.4.0...
Installed primitive-0.5.4.0
Configuring ref-tf-0.4...
Building ref-tf-0.4...
Installed ref-tf-0.4
Configuring StateVar-1.1.0.0...
Building StateVar-1.1.0.0...
Configuring distributive-0.4.4...
Installed StateVar-1.1.0.0
Building distributive-0.4.4...
Configuring dependent-map-0.1.1.3...
Installed distributive-0.4.4
Building dependent-map-0.1.1.3...
Configuring vector-0.10.12.3...
Installed dependent-map-0.1.1.3
Building vector-0.10.12.3...
Installed text-1.2.1.1
Configuring hashable-1.2.3.2...
Building hashable-1.2.3.2...
Installed hashable-1.2.3.2
Configuring unordered-containers-0.2.5.1...
Building unordered-containers-0.2.5.1...
Installed unordered-containers-0.2.5.1
Configuring semigroups-0.16.2.2...
Building semigroups-0.16.2.2...
Installed semigroups-0.16.2.2
Configuring void-0.7...
Configuring bifunctors-5...
Installed vector-0.10.12.3
Building void-0.7...
Building bifunctors-5...
Installed void-0.7
Configuring contravariant-1.3.1.1...
Building contravariant-1.3.1.1...
Installed contravariant-1.3.1.1
Configuring comonad-4.2.6...
Installed bifunctors-5
Building comonad-4.2.6...
Installed comonad-4.2.6
Configuring profunctors-5.1.1...
Configuring semigroupoids-5.0.0.2...
Building profunctors-5.1.1...
Building semigroupoids-5.0.0.2...
Installed profunctors-5.1.1
Installed semigroupoids-5.0.0.2
Downloading these-0.4.1...
Configuring these-0.4.1...
Building these-0.4.1...
Installed these-0.4.1
```

This seems an awful lot.

Are these exactly the packages contained in the dependency tree of Reflex ?

I suspect yes, but I am not sure, hence this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite. At the moment, anything in the global package database is also used by sandboxes. I believe future versions of cabal-install will restrict this to a few whitelisted core packages that ship with GHC (and that shouldn't/can't be replaced anyway).

Comment: Hm, which global database?

Comment: @jhegedus There is only one. You can see what's in it with `ghc-pkg list --global`.